# How to workaround auto-omitting files/folders starting with "_" (underscore) in assets folder

Tags: android, cordova, dojo

I want to deploy **PhoneGap** app on the Android simulator provided with eclipse. I decided to use **Dojo Toolkit** which heavily relies on the " _ " convention (starting a file/folder with " _ " means this is a private/internal module).

Basically the problem is that while deploying the app, every file/folder starting with "_" is omitted. This completely messes things up, **Dojo toolkit** as exptected fails to work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go star this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343) so Google will fix the bug eventually. If you are running on Mac or Linux there is a patched aapt that fixes the bug [here](http://hanji.info:8002/download/utils/). Other than that your only choice is to do a [build](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) of Dojo so that it is only in one file.

Comment: I am downvoting this as the only part to solve the issue with the bug fix is a broken link. The answer should include the solution which is stated in other answers just a few lines in the gradle file.

Answer (score 7):

```
aaptOptions{
    ignoreAssetsPattern  '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
}
```

add the above lines in the application build.gradle file inside android block for android app

Answer (score 2):

From the previous answer I ended making changes on `ant.properties` which is located at root of project with this:

`aapt.ignore.assets=!.svn:!.git:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*.scc:*~`

Here, I overwrote `aapt.ignore.assets` property defined on sdk-android directory. It works

Answer (score 2):

For any Dojo developers out there, or anyone having issues with this in general.

What fixed it for me in Android Studio is opening the build.gradle, then adding to the android block:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    ...

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern '!._'
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, the compileSdkVersion doesn't matter at all. This seems to affect Android 4.4+

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to use dojo.js from the CDN

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Also, I started looking for a minify app or service, which could create a single file from all the required dojo files, but did not find one easily.

Comment: I know this is old, but - Dojo has its own build system, see https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/ .. e.g. this post http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/android_build_missing_files?full_site=1 shows an example of a build profile and build command line. I haven't tested what they say there, but the idea is the same as here, to put all the Dojo files that normally reside in folders starting with an underscore into one large .js file during build, so your android app doesn't need to reference the folders any more (and your apk will be smaller).