# dojox mobile trouble in TextBox Widget and android theme

Tags: css, cordova, dojo

I developed a form that contains dojox.mobile.TextBox using phonegap
I got a problem I used the dojo.require("dojox.mobile.TextBox");

> 04-26 20:55:42.196: D/PhoneGapLog(446): file:///android_asset/www/dojo/dojo.js: Line 15 : Error: declare dojox.mobile.TextBox: mixin #1 is unknown. Did you use dojo.require to pull it in?
>
> 04-26 15:35:04.916: E/Web Console(446): Error: declare dojox.mobile.TextBox: mixin #1 is unknown. Did you use dojo.require to pull it in? at file:///android_asset/www/dojo/dojo.js:15

I also don't see the css theme of android in my device but I can see it on firefox on my desktop. what is the problem, could you help please and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343) in the android build tools

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212288/239408 for workarounds.