# non compiling assets folder

Tags: android, assets

Hi and hope someone may be able to help.

I'm writing an app that is based on some original artwork and I'm wanting to store several large (Adobe Illustrator) files in the same folder as the app's package. Because these files are large I don't want them to be included when I get to the stage of exporting the app to an apk file.

Traditionally I'd use the assets folder for this but the contents of this folder would get compiled into the apk file.

Does anyone have any suggestions for folders that won't get compiled in the export process.

My thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible to exclude `asset` folder from export process. However what you can do is use `APK Expansion Files` for providing added things or you can download files at client end. For more information regarding APK Expansion files please read this : http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Thanks dreamcoder, I came across this issue a year or so ago and someone had a method for doing it, sadly I can't remember the details but it wasn't anything to do with the assets folder.

Comment: I would love to know the process. If it can be done then it will be a great news for devs.

Comment: Got it! It's folders starting with an underscore that get ommitted from the build e.g. _assets It's reported as a problem on this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206117/how-to-workaround-autoomitting-fiiles-folders-starting-with-underscore-in]

Comment: Hmm..thats good...but how are you going to access `_assets` folder?

Comment: You can place them in any folder which you 'invent' in the root of your project.

Comment: There's a limit of 1MB per file and the size of your app can't exceed 50MB, excluding the expansion files.